# how to disable all smileys and char combinations in teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

MS Teams was selected as a communication tool in our company. We do post code into it. And that code contains asterisks, underscores and even numbers! I understand it's business critical feature, but will never, ever, ever need smiley face, smiley face with sunglasses, or part of my code arbitrarily missing stars/underscores and get arbitrarily boldened/empahsized. Even if I write message as code, the asterisks still mingles the text.

Is it somehow possible to turn all these off? Settings or some message header? To send message 'as it was written', without any teenage beautifications?

**UPDATE:** regarding pressing `>`  to enter verbatim text:

[image]

I entered "does not", shift enter, then "really work", go up and created section for text supposed to be verbatim. It really does not work. Then I tried to start immediately with "> " and it equally does not work. On 3rd attempt I noticed some glitching, as I was able to enter bold text, but smiley face did not replace :) To conclude, I'd say "> " unlocks new layer of MS Teams instability and bugs, but cannot be used to enter verbatim text.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a simple code block, you can send text as code by starting the line with `>`  (enter <kbd>></kbd> then press <kbd>Space</kbd>).

[image: Starting a new chat in Microsoft Teams]

[image: Opening a code block in the Teams chat]

Typing in this code block will still replace matching patterns with smilies/emoji, but pasting will not. You should be able to paste your code without issue.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to escape the code block.

[image: Pasting code into the code block]

Formatting is retained after sending the message (including leading whitespace which would have been stripped without the code block).

[image: Viewing the code block in the sent chat]

---

If you need more advanced features, there's a code snippet button hidden in the advanced editor.

[image: Starting a new chat in Microsoft Teams. The advanced editor button is highlighted to show its location]

[image: The advanced editor with the code snippet button highlighted to show its location]

After clicking the code snippet button, a modal will open.

[image: The code snippet modal open]

You can name the snippet, choose whether or not to wrap text in the snippet, and pick a language to provide highlighting in the snippet. Under these options is a field to paste your code.

[image: The code snippet modal with a joke implementation of foobar to show the features of the tool]

Once you finish setting up the snippet, click the Insert button to add the snippet to the current message. You can continue editing the message.

[image: The Teams message showing the snippet preview]

Click the "Send Message" (arrow) button as normal to send the message.

[image: The sent message showing a preview of the snippet]

Click the "Expand Preview" link to show the whole code block with the chosen language syntax applied.

[image: The sent message showing an expanded code block]

Comment: Sorry, does not work. See update.

Comment: fair enough, so it works for pasting, but not for typing. Meaning if you're writing the code from top of your head, it will get mingled in this code block as well as without it. Especialy if you use ` it will become ugly. Then it's actually not that useful, because if you're typing and not pasting, you have to open external editor and write it there. If you copy-paste this, even without code block, it will be treated as literals. :) won't become smiley, not bold formatting etc. So workaround: create script,which lauches dialog to enter text and does copy paste to teams on exit. Shameful,works.

Comment: @MartinMucha I found another feature and have added it to the answer